# Python List Creation Difference

Tags: python-3.x, list, recursion

I am trying to create a recursive function to sort the list from low to high. 
Following code doesn't work

```
less = []
greater = []
def quicksort(array):
    if len(array)<2:
        return array
    else:
        pivot = array[0]
        for i in array[1:]:
            if i <= pivot:
                less.append(i)
            else:
                greater.append(i)
        return quicksort(less)+[pivot]+quicksort(greater)
print(quicksort([1,3,2,7,8]))
```

but I use a book code , it works. Would you advise me why?

```
def quicksort(array):
    if len(array)<2:
        return array
    else:
        pivot = array[0]
        less = [i for i in array[1:] if  i <= pivot]
        greater = [i for i in array[1:] if i > pivot]
        return quicksort(less)+[pivot]+quicksort(greater)
print(quicksort([1,3,2,7,8]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using *global* `less` and `greater` `list`s, so you're going to end up building up the `list`s bigger and bigger and bigger, repeating your inputs many times (roughly proportional to the number of times you recursively call `quicksort`). `less` and `greater` keep growing until you blow the stack depth limit or run out of memory and Python dies to protect you from yourself.

Worse, you preserve state across calls, so the second and subsequent things you `quicksort` ends up including garbage from the prior sort operations, even if they're on inputs so short you could "sort" them trivially. Your code would work if you made `less`/`greater` local, initializing them afresh in each call:

```
def quicksort(array):
    if len(array)<2:
        return array
    else:
        pivot = array[0]
        less = []     # Local!
        greater = []  # Local!
        for i in array[1:]:
            if i <= pivot:
                less.append(i)
            else:
                greater.append(i)
        return quicksort(less)+[pivot]+quicksort(greater)
```